# Getting Ya&#x15F;am instead of Yaşam using export in SimpleXMLElement in php

Tags: php, xml, encoding, cdata

I'm trying to export an XML using SimpleXMLElement and getting the characters changing.

I tried using different encodings, inserting CDATA as a string and it solved nothing.

What am I missing?

Export code:

```
<?php 

// Create a new XML
$xmlExport = new SimpleXMLElement('<Products/>');

// Add a new node.        
$product = $xmlExport->addChild('Product');

// Adding Yaşam.
$product->addChild('Category');
$product->Category = "Yaşam";

// Exporting the new XML
$xmlExport->asXML('xml.xml');

 ?>
```

The result I get:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Products>
    <Product>
        <Category>Ya&#x15F;am</Category>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

The expected result:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Products>
    <Product>
        <Category>Yaşam</Category>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

I SOLVED THE PROBLEM

I found the problem, I read somewhere that SimpleXMLElement by default uses UTF-8 encoding, It seems that information was wrong or not working in my case.

I changed

```
$xmlExport = new SimpleXMLElement('<Products/>');
```

to

```
$xmlExport = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Products/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I read somewhere that SimpleXMLElement by default uses UTF-8 encoding, It seems that information was wrong or not working in my case.

I changed

```
$xmlExport = new SimpleXMLElement('<Products/>');
```

to

```
$xmlExport = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Products/>");
```